# Xcode swift SKScene in app purchase

Tags: xcode, swift, in-app-purchase, skscene

I'm trying to create in app purchases on an `SKScene` in my game. The scene is called coinShop. Basically, an IAP that gives the user 300 coins. When I tried copying code, it said SKScene can not conform to the delegates I tried adding. If anybody knows how do in app purchases with a scene instead of a viewcontroller, I would love to know. Here is all the code relating to in app purchases

in the didMoveToView(), i have

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)

    requestProductInfo()

    productIDs.append("com.ClearRockTechnologies.alien-anarchy.300Coins")
```

and then i have the following functions

```
func requestProductInfo() {
    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        let productIdentifiers = NSSet(array: productIDs)
        let productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as Set<NSObject> )

        productRequest.delegate = self
        productRequest.start()
    }
    else {
        print("Cannot perform In App Purchases.")
    }
}






func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
    if response.products.count != 0 {
        for product in response.products {
            productsArray.append(product)
        }

    }
    else {
        print("There are no products.")
    }



    if response.invalidProductIdentifiers.count != 0 {
        print(response.invalidProductIdentifiers.description)
    }
}

func showActions() {

    let payment = SKPayment(product: self.productsArray[0] as SKProduct)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
    //self.transactionInProgress = true
}


func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    for transaction in transactions as! [SKPaymentTransaction] {
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case SKPaymentTransactionState.Purchased:
            print("Transaction completed successfully.")
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
            coins+=300
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(coins, forKey: "coins")
        case SKPaymentTransactionState.Failed:
            print("Transaction Failed");
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)

        default:
            print(transaction.transactionState.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

and here are my two errors,

1. Type 'coinShop' does not conform to protocol 'SKPaymentTransactionObserver'
2. 'NSSet' is not implicitly convertible to 'Set'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?

Error 1 has no suggestion, and error 2 tells me to add as "Set< NSObject >" to this line 
`let productRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as Set<NSObject> )`
 but I clearly already have that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "can not conform to the delegates" - this means you need to look at the protocol you declared, and implement the required methods.

Comment: I added code examples to it

Comment: P.S, yes I have import StoreKit at the top